# xperf call stack functions: "System\Interrupts + DPCs"

Tags: windows, profiling, xperf

While profiling Windows performance with xperf, I've collected a trace and have the call stack data. If if keep digging in to the call stack, the trace sometimes ends with `System\Interrupts + DPCs` or with `System\ETW overhead`.

I've attached a stack trace showing the same:

[image]

The collapsed trace is again calls to `System\Interrupts + DPCs<itself>`

What do these stack entries mean? What functions are being called here? Is it safe to ignore it (though, I doubt this)?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking at are Frame Tags. This is an optional display where a bunch of actual calls are collapsed under a meaningful description (tag). 
You can see the actual stack by displaying a different column ("Stack", without the word Tag in the name).

If you look at the trace properies you will find find a link to a tag definitions file. You can edit it or supply your own. This helps in thematically combining related stack calls for faster analysis.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/stack-tags

Comment: Git it. Stack tags groups functions together at the start. Stack frame tags groups functions at the very end of the stack.